# How to access list property of derived type through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Consider this code sample:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public virtual void DoThing() {
        ...
    }
}

public class DerivedClass {
    public override void DoThing() {
        ...
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public List<DerivedClass> MyProp {get; set;}
}

...

// assume we have obj of SomeClass and prop as PropertyInfo of MyProp

var pt = prop.PropertyType;

if (pt.IsGeneric && (pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) && (pt.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass))))
{
    var val = pt.GetValue(obj); // here it is not null 
    var list = val as List<BaseClass>; // list is null
    list?.ForEach(o => o.DoThing());
}
```

How can I get list of `BaseClass` and call (probably) overridden method for each of them? As I try to cast property value to list it become `null`.

Comment: The thing is, while `DerivedClass` is a descendant of `BaseClass`, `List<DerivedClass>` **is not a descendant of** `List<BaseClass>`. The latter types are two completely different (and unrelated) things. That's why the `as` operator resolves to `null`. The type does not match. However, in a loop iterating `val` you could be successful casting **each item** to `BaseClass`.

Comment: ^^ Like `val?.ForEach(o => ((BaseClass)o).DoThing());`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @Fildor I figured out the solution:

```
var en = val as IEnumerable;
foreach (var o in en) {
    (o as BaseClass)?.DoThing();
}
```